# When 'unwrapping' child nodes in a loop, the references become confused

Tags: javascript

```
var thumbs = document.getElementsByClassName('thumbnailImage');
                for(var i=0,len=thumbs.length;i<len;i++){
                    var p = thumbs[i].parentNode;
                    alert('i: '+i+',thumbs[i]: '+thumbs[i].id+',p.tagName: '+p.tagName+',p.class: '+p.className);
                    //unpackchild(thumbs[i]);
                }

function unpackchild(c) {
    var g=c.parentNode.parentNode;g.appendChild(c);
}
```

There are 5 image elements in thumbs (this is correct) and each one is wrapped in an anchor tag. When I run the code above (after document ready) the first three images are unpacked to the grandparent div correctly but on the last two the id I see in the alert is a repeat of the first two as though thumbs[3] now references thumbs[0] and thumbs[4] now references thumbs[1] (the ids are unique).

Does anybody see what I could have done to cause this or is this something intrinsic to the way javascript references elements (by parent perhaps)?

Answer (score 1):

Change your loop to:

```
for( var i=thumbs.length-1; i>=0; i--) {
```

This will ensure that the system doesn't get confused, even if you have nested elements with that class name (you probably don't in this case, but it's good to know in general [;)](http://xkcd.com/541/) )

Comment: Actually, you might want to consider using `document.querySelectorAll(".thumbnailImage")` instead. It's a snapshot rather than a live collection, which means you can loop in either direction with no problem. Additionally, IE8 will work (ie supports QSA but not gEBCN)

Answer (score 1):

`HTMLCollection` object returned by `getElementsByClassName` is live - it means it may change whenever underlying DOM document change.

Comment: yes this was what i suspected. Reversing the order and using the loop style Niet the Dark suggested has resolved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Combining the two answers above, while looping, anything occurring after i moved the elements, was breaking the references to thumbs. So in the original ( i removed it for the question) i was adding an eventlistener after unpackchild was called. After changing to the backward counting loop suggested by Niet, the eventlistener was actually just added 5 times onto the first element in thumbs. By moving addeventlistener to before unpackchild, it was added correctly to each element.

So with this a click on thumbs[0] results in 5 click events firing all referencing thumbs[0]...

```
                    var thumbs = document.getElementsByClassName('thumbnailImage'),i=0,len=thumbs.length,c=0,el=[],p;
                    for(i=len-1;i>=0;i--){
                        p = thumbs[i].parentNode;
                        //alert('i: '+i+',thumbs[i]: '+thumbs[i].id+',p.tagName: '+p.tagName+',p.class: '+p.className);
                        thumbs[i].addEventListener('click',(function(t){return function(e){mzremix(t,e);};})(thumbs[i]),false);
                        if(p.tagName == 'A'){ unpackchild(thumbs[i]);p.parentNode.removeChild(p); }
                        thumbs[i].addEventListener('click',(function(t){return function(e){mzremix(t,e);};})(thumbs[i]),false);
                    }
```

...while this results in the correct 1 event firing for each thumbs[i] referencing thumbs[i]

```
                var thumbs = document.getElementsByClassName('thumbnailImage'),i=0,len=thumbs.length,c=0,el=[],p;
                for(i=len-1;i>=0;i--){
                    p = thumbs[i].parentNode;
                    //alert('i: '+i+',thumbs[i]: '+thumbs[i].id+',p.tagName: '+p.tagName+',p.class: '+p.className);
                    thumbs[i].addEventListener('click',(function(t){return function(e){mzremix(t,e);};})(thumbs[i]),false);
                    if(p.tagName == 'A'){ unpackchild(thumbs[i]);p.parentNode.removeChild(p); }
                }
```